# Using selector to change ListView background color

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to change the background color of the items of a ListView when selected but only the `state_pressed` is actually working.

The ListView code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
chaptersAdapter = new ChaptersAdapter();
listView.setAdapter(chaptersAdapter);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        onListItemCheck(i, view);
        return true;
    }
});
```

ChaptersAdapter:

```
private class ChaptersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Chapter> data;

    public ChaptersAdapter(ArrayList<Chapter> data) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chapters_item, null);
        }
        TextView chapterText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chapterText);
        chapterText.setText("Chapter: " + data.get(i).number);
        TextView pagesText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pagesText);
        pagesText.setText("Pages: " + data.get(i).pagesRead + "/" + data.get(i).pagesTotal);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I tried with `setItemChecked`:

```
private void onListItemCheck(int position, View view)
{
    listView.setItemChecked(position, !listView.isItemChecked(position));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked: " + listView.isItemChecked(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And with `setActivated`:

```
private void onListItemCheck(int position, View view)
{
    view.setActivated(!view.isActivated());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activated: " + view.isActivated(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

ListView layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.library.Chapters"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ListView item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:library="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/chapters_listview_selector">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mankin="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapterText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pagesText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:text="Page: 0/0"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
      android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:state_active="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**SOLUTION:**
I typed wrong the selector, the correct is `state_activated` not `state_active`

Comment: do u want to change the background color of the list item or list item name?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove code from state_pressed and add in state_selete.